# Python pandas, calculate average temperature sensor for 15 minutes before survey was filled in (match timestamps + add new column)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, time

I am trying to add new columns behind an excel consisting of survey data (=PIT_da.xlsx). In those columns the average sensor values (e.g. temperature)in the 15, 30, and 60 minutes before the survey was filled in should be calculated and added. The sensor data is in the excel file "IEQ_da.xlsx" (incl timestamp).

I started like this:

```
#import raw file
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfSD = pd.read_excel('IEQ_da.xlsx')
dfPIT = pd.read_excel('PIT_da.xlsx')

#main aim: add after each survey result row in PIT_da.xlsx columns for the average values of the indoor environmental quality parameters in 15/30/60 minutes before submitting the survey

#Step 0: set both timestamp and submitdate to right datetime object
dfSD['timestamp'] =  pd.to_datetime(dfSD['timestamp'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')
dfPIT['submitdate'] =  pd.to_datetime(dfPIT['submitdate'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')

#Step 1: introduce arrays and set to numpy
array1 = dfSD[['timestamp']].to_numpy().ravel()
array2 = dfPIT[['submitdate']].to_numpy().ravel()
data_sensorID = dfSD[['devid']].to_numpy().ravel()
survey_sensorID = dfPIT[['PIT5']].to_numpy().ravel()Each survey has a timestamp (=submitdate) and should be matched to the sensor data at that timestamp.
```

The time is converted to number to be able to calculate the difference in 15min /30min/ 60min

```
#Step 2: set timestamps to number and define a match 
from datetime import datetime
def timestamps(x) : 
    Timestamps = np.empty(x.size)
    for i in range(x.size) : 
        date = x[i]
        dt64 = np.datetime64(date)
        timestamp = (dt64 - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
        Timestamps[i] = timestamp
    return Timestamps

array1TS = timestamps(array1)
array2TS = timestamps(array2)
```

Next, a match is made for each survey submittime and sensor timestamp (rounded to nearest 5 minutes already), incl the condition of being from the same sensor device ID (=devid) and PIT5 (question in survey which asked the sensor ID of the sensor nearby).

```
#Step 3: define match with conditions: must be same timestamp and must have same sensor ID, by means of a matrix
Match = np.empty([array1TS.size, array2TS.size])
for i in range(array1TS.size) : 
    for j in range(array2TS.size):
        if (data_sensorID[i] == survey_sensorID[j]):
            if (array1TS[i] == array2TS[j]):
                Match[i,j] = 1;
            else: 
                Match[i,j] = 0;
```

Now, with this match a new column should be added to "PIT_da.xlsx", with the average value of the e.g. 15 minutes before the matched time stamps of the column "SENtemp" in de IEQ_da.xlsx file (with temperature values).

The questions: 
1. How to go from the "match" to selecting all rows from that timestamp 15 minutes before the matched timestamp. 
2. How to calculate the average of these selected rows (neglecting empty cells) and place it in a new column in PIT_da.xlsx (this new column should be named "SENtemp_15" , for the temperature in the 15 min before the survey was filled in).

For reference some rows of the data used:

IEQ_da.xlsx

```
    import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp' : ['14/04/2020  00:18:00', '14/04/2020  00:18:05', '14/04/2020  00:17:55', '14/04/2020  00:17:50' , '14/04/2020  00:17:40', '14/04/2020  00:17:40', '14/04/2020  00:17:20', '14/04/2020  00:17:20'], 'devid' : ['4', '2', '4', '2', '4' , '2' , '4' , '2'], 
                       'SENtemp' : ['20,2', '18,8', '20,1', '19', '20,2', '18,8', '20,1', '18,9']})
df
```

PIT_da.xlsx

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'submitdate' : ['14/04/2020  00:18:00', '14/04/2020  00:18:05'], 'PIT5' : ['4', '2'],
                   })
df
```

I hope someone is willing to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 initial steps are rather useless. You can directly use `apply` on `dfPIT` to build the new column(s). The hardest part is that `SENtemp` is a string column with comma as decimal point which cannot be directly converted into float. Possible code:

```
delta = [15, 30, 60]  # delta in minutes

columns = [f'Average{i}' for i in delta]  # column names per delta values

dfPIT[columns] = dfPIT.apply(axis=1, func=lambda x: pd.Series(
    [dfSD.loc[(dfSD['timestamp']>x['submitdate'] - pd.Timedelta(i, 'T'))
              &(dfSD['timestamp']<=x['submitdate']), 'SENtemp']
     .str.replace(',','.').astype('float').mean() for i in delta],
    index=columns))
```

With your sample data, it gives:

```
           submitdate PIT5  Average15  Average30  Average60
0 2020-04-14 00:18:00    4  19.614286  19.614286  19.614286
1 2020-04-14 00:18:05    2  19.512500  19.512500  19.512500
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, never could have done that myself! One last question: the timestamp and submitdate match is not the only match which should be made. The 'devid' column in IEQ data and the 'PIT5' in the PIT data should matched as well (=device ID). I have many devices (sensors) and the average should only be calculated over the same devices for the same surveys. How could I incorporate in the script you just made?

Comment: [dfSD.loc[(dfSD['timestamp']>x['submitdate'] - pd.Timedelta(i, 'T'))
              &(dfSD['timestamp']<=x['submitdate'])&(dfSD['devid']==dfPIT['PIT5']), 'SENtemp'] Would this work?